# Show that the hyperplane $H=\{x \in\mathbf{R} \;|\; : {A}^{T} x =b\}$ is closed in $\mathbf{R}^d$.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $A \in \mathbf{R}^d \backslash \{0\}$ and $b\in\mathbf{R}$. Show that the hyperplane $H=\{x \in\mathbf{R} \;|\; : {A}^{T} x =b\}$ is closed in $\mathbf{R}^d$.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I just edited the question and answered it

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but please note I have changed one bit back to {A}^{T}.

Answer (score 0):

It is the inverse image of $\{b\}$, which is closed in $\mathbf{R}$, by the continuous map $x\mapsto {}^{t} A x $ from $\mathbf{R}^d$ to $\mathbf{R}$. It is therefore closed.

Please validate my answer if you are satisfied by it.

Comment: I am not sure, my question is for {A}^{T} not ^{t}

Comment: $T$ or $t$ is the same, it means the transposed of the vector... Now, you can validate ;-)

Comment: $T$ or $t$ is the same, it means the transposed of the vector, you can put it after of before $A$, it is just a matter of notation...

Comment: Is there any other way to prove it? I don't understand the continuous map part, or why this implies it is closed.

Comment: A map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if for every closed subset $Z$ of $Y$ the subset $f^{-1} (Z)$ of $X$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: You know that $H$ is closed if and only it is stable by convergence : let $(x_n)_n $ be a sequence of elements in $X$ converging to $x\in\mathbf{R}^d$. Then for each $n$ you have ${}^{t} A x = {}^{t} A (x-x_n) + \underbrace{{}^{t} A x_n}_{=0}$ because $x_n \in H$, and then $\|{}^{t} A x\| = \| {}^{t} A (x-x_n) \| \leq \|A\| \|x-x_n\| \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$. Passing to the limit, you get $\|{}^{t} A x\- = 0$, that is ${}^{t} A x = 0$, showing that $x\in H$. Therefore, $H$ is closed.